# Can we create partially colored text in Processing?

Tags: java, processing

I want to learn to create partially colored text/String in processing(java) like below example. It can be 10% white 90% black. or any ratio for any two color. I would like to learn how to do it in processing.

[image: Text Example]

Comment: One can try using javaFX's [Text](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/text/jfxpub-text.htm).

Answer (score 4):

## Option 1: In Processing

Render your text into a PGraphics object and then iterate over the pixels[] of the object to change the colour of a proportion of the text.

In the example below, the colour ratio will not be correct unless you create a PGraphics object of the exact dimensions of the text - I'm not sure whether there is a programmatic way to determine the required dimensions. *(As a result, I'm using a ratio of 0.6 to recolour the top ~50% of the text in the example).*

Furthermore, *noSmooth()* has been called on the object as anti-aliasing will create pixels that aren't quite the original text colour, which makes replacing them more complicated than simply checking for equality *(==)*.

```
import processing.core.PApplet;
import processing.core.PGraphics;

public class Text extends PApplet {

PGraphics text;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    PApplet.main(Text.class);
}

@Override
public void settings() {
    size(400, 400);
}

@Override
public void setup() {
    makeText();
}

@Override
public void draw() {
    background(55);
    image(text, 100, 100);
}

public void makeText() {
    final int orange = color(255,165,0);
    final int yellow = color(255,255,0);
    final float ratio = 0.6f;

    text = createGraphics(150, 60);
    text.noSmooth();
    text.beginDraw();
    text.fill(orange);
    text.textSize(60);
    text.textAlign(LEFT, TOP);
    text.loadPixels();
    text.text("TEXT", 0, 0);
    text.endDraw();
    
    for (int pixel = 0; pixel < (text.pixels.length * ratio); pixel++) {
        if (text.pixels[pixel] == orange) {
            text.pixels[pixel] = yellow;
        }
    }
}
}
```

#### Result:

[image]

---

## Option 2: With JavaFX

This is a hacky method, but it gives better results since the text is anti-aliased. This method requires that your sketch be in `FX2D` rendering mode, which can be prescribed in the `size()` call.

Expose the stackPane belonging to the PApplet (this is where the JavaFX text object will be added):

```
Canvas canvas = (Canvas) ((PSurfaceFX) getSurface()).getNative();
StackPane p = (StackPane) canvas.getParent();
```

Create a JavaFX text object. I am using a CSS style (a linear gradient with immediate cutoff) for the partially-coloured effect.

```
javafx.scene.text.Text t = new javafx.scene.text.Text("TEXT");
t.setCache(true);
t.setFont(Font.font(null, FontWeight.NORMAL, 60));
t.setStyle("-fx-fill:linear-gradient( from 100.0% 100.0% to 100.0% 0.0%, rgb(255, 165, 0) 0.5," + "rgb(255, 255, 0)" +" 0.5);");
```

Finally, add the text to the PApplet's stage stackpane (which was exposed earlier):

```
p.getChildren().add(t);
```

#### Result (note the anti-aliasing):

[image]

Also note that you'lll need to use `t.setVisible()` to toggle visibility since this text element is entirely separate from Processing's drawing canvas.

Comment: Nice answer (+1) ! Additionally, for option 1, one way to to use a [mask()](https://processing.org/reference/PImage_mask_.html) which is less efficient but more flexible or an additive [blend() mode](https://processing.org/reference/blend_.html) which might be faster, but less flexible